# Window.getComputedStyle does not implement interface Element error in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like to append some data to the HTML element, so I've used the following code:

```
$("#bookListDiv").append(data.HTMLString);
```

and everything has working, but then I'd like to add a fadein animation while displaying this element, so I've modified it to:

```
$(data.HTMLString).hide().appendTo("#bookListDiv").fadeIn(1000);
```

Animation is working on Chrome but on Firefox I see the following error in console:
TypeError: Argument 1 of Window.getComputedStyle does not implement interface Element.
I'm using jquery 1.8.2.

Could you advise me what can be wrong? I supposed something with data, but in the first approach everything is working correctly.

Comment: Try `getComputedStyle(document.createElement('div'))` in console, what's the result? Which version of Firefox is used?

Comment: The key bit of information would seem to be in the value of `data.HTMLString`.

Comment: I think I may know the issue, but don't want to sit here and guess. When asking a question, provide all relevant information needed to reproduce the issue.

Comment: cookie monster, please don't spam if you don't know the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution by adding the delay before fadeIn function.
Code after changes:

```
$(data.HTMLString).hide().appendTo("#bookListDiv").delay(100).fadeIn(1000);
```

As I've noticed the number in delay is should be adjusted to the size of data, in my case for 7KB json data it is working, but I've started from 1000.

Answer (score 2):

You will also get this if you call `getComputedStyle`on `<html>`. It should be common sense, but I had a recursive function that was bubbling up from inner elements with this function and giving the error when it ended up at the document root.

Answer (score 1):

This problem was wontfixed in jQuery: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12462.

The workaround is to wrap your HTML in a single element before giving it to jQuery.

Comment: What do you mean by wrapping the HTML in a single element before giving it to jQuery?  Do you have an example you can show in the code?

Answer (score 0):

Try making sure you're using correct markup syntax as well.

I'm using AngularJS to dynamically change the disabled button state while at the same time hiding/showing a button... this made Firefox freakout with the "Window.getComputedStyle does not implement interface Element" error (but  Safari/Chrome/IE).

In my case the real issue was that the markup I was working with did not have matching opening/closing tags: `<button ng-disabled="!x">Click</div>`

Once corrected: `<button ng-disabled="!x">Click</button>` things were fine.

Strangely, both previous answers were partial solutions though: wrapping a $timeout around my hiding/showing as the first-posted answer suggested worked (but the delay had to be a substantial amount) and wrapping the element in an additional element worked as well but was not the implementation I needed (and created other issues).

I've tried but simply cannot get a code sample working to reproduce this issue.