# does not implement interface Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, polymer

First off, I've check [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22849138/window-getcomputedstyle-does-not-implement-interface-element-error-in-firefox) and it doesn't quite seem to address the issue I'm having.

The code I'm using looks like this and for whatever reason, it refuses to run in Firefox and is giving an error of "Argument 1 of Window.getDefaultComputedStyle does not implement interface Element". This code is designed to switch tabs and can currently be found at [testing.worldwidejamie.com](http://testing.worldwidejamie.com).

Here is my full code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var content = undefined;

    $('#tabs .tab-list li').each(function(){

    $(this).on('click',function() {

        // buttons
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        // content

        if(content !== undefined){
            content.hide();
        }

        var currentAttrValue = $("a", this).attr('href');
        content = $(currentAttrValue);

        content.show(); 


        });
    });

});
```

This works in the latest builds of Chrome, Safari, and IE but not in Firefox.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What is it that you expect wrapping a jQuery object around an "href" value to do?

Comment: The `href`s in this particular case are `#tab2`, etc., matching elements in the document.

Comment: It looks to me as if the Polymer stuff is making it such that $("#tab1") wraps a plain JavaScript object and not a DOM node. On the subsequent call to `.show()`, then, jQuery is asking the browser for the current effective style for something that's not an HTML element, and boom.

Comment: Why are you using each to add click event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code for the tabs works without fail. The problem is actually in your **platform.js** script. After checking the console output for the page via Firebug, the script breaks inside that script.

You can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/Au7EJ/3/ that your **tabs.js** script runs as you would expect. Only made one change to your code because there is no need to initialize 'content' with a value, so I changed it in the fiddle.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var content; // just a declaration is enough here
    $('#tabs .tab-list li').each(function () {
        $(this).on('click', function () {
            // buttons
            $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
            // content
            if (content !== undefined) {
                content.hide();
            }
            var currentAttrValue = $("a", this).attr('href');
            content = $(currentAttrValue);
            content.show();
        });
    });
});
```

Hope this sheds some light on your problem!

Comment: This was helpful. I think the issue is that platform.js isn't fully compatible with all browsers yet. I guess it's back to the drawing board...  Thanks for your help.